# Subsonic 3.0 UPDATE, multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

```
      db.Update<Luna.Record.TB_ITEM>().Set(
                x => x.ITEM_DURABILITY == Convert.ToInt32(quantity))
                .Where(x => x.ITEM_POSITION == Convert.ToInt32(position))
                .Execute();
```

How will I add an AND clause this is how it looks like in plain SQL:

```
UPDATE TB_ITEM
SET ITEM_DURABITLITY=@quantity
WHERE ITEM_POSITION=@position AND CHARACTER_IDX=@charidx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Where(x => x.ITEM_POSITION == Convert.ToInt32(position)
            && x.CHARACTER_IDX == Convert.ToInt32(charidx))
```

Comment: Luna.Record.GameDBDB db = new Luna.Record.GameDBDB();
            db.Update<Luna.Record.TB_ITEM>().Set(x => x.ITEM_DURABILITY == Convert.ToInt32(quantity))
                .Where(x => x.CHARACTER_IDX == Convert.ToInt32(Session["CharIndex"].ToString()) && x.ITEM_POSITION == Convert.ToInt32(position))
                .Execute();

Hi I have these now, But it doesn't seem to update the database.