# How to write this sql query with SubSonic3?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

```
UPDATE  Scenarios.Blocks 
SET     OrderId = OrderId - 1
```

So, it's basically updating a column with its current value minus one.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
db.Update<Blocks>.Set(x => x.OrderId == x.OrderId - 1).Execute();
```

If you want to have a where clause for your update query: [Subsonic 3.0 UPDATE, multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623115/subsonic-3-0-update-multiple-conditions)